# How to update the dropdown box when the data is updated in shiny

Tags: r, shiny

After updating(adding/editing new rows) the table (database), the choices in the dropdown box are not getting updated immediately. Even though when the page is refreshed it is not getting updated. Until and unless i run the whole app again.

```r
result <- dbSendQuery(dbConn, "select * from testing_mapping")

data <- dbFetch(result)

unique_ClientRoll <- unique(data$`Client Roll UP`)

Ui <- selectInput("Client Rollup", label = "Client Roll UP",unique_ClientRoll)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
observeEvent(input$submit,{
#inserting some new ClientRoll taken from user 
dbSendQuery(dbConn, paste0("INSERT INTO testing_mapping VALUES ", values, ";"))
})
}
```

After inserting new values into DB, the dropdown should update with the new values.

**Edit 1:**
Used **Reactive function** to update the dropdown every time -

```
result <- dbSendQuery(dbConn, "select * from testing_mapping")

data <- dbFetch(result)

Ui <- selectInput("Client Rollup", label = "Client Roll UP",unique_ClientRoll())

server <- function(input, output, session) {
unique_ClientRoll <- reactive({unique(data$`Client Roll UP`)})

observeEvent(input$submit,{
#inserting some new ClientRoll taken from user 
dbSendQuery(dbConn, paste0("INSERT INTO testing_mapping VALUES ", values, ";"))
})
}
```

After running this i'm getting a error saying **Attempt to apply non-function**

**Edit 2:**
Used **Selectupdateinput** to update the dropdown -

```
result <- dbSendQuery(dbConn, "select * from testing_mapping")

data <- dbFetch(result)

unique_ClientRoll <- unique(data$`Client Roll UP`)

Ui <- selectInput("Client Rollup", label = "Client Roll UP",unique_ClientRoll)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
observeEvent(input$submit,{
#inserting some new ClientRoll taken from user 
dbSendQuery(dbConn, paste0("INSERT INTO testing_mapping VALUES ", values, ";"))

#again pulling the updated data after changes
result <- dbSendQuery(dbConn, "select * from testing_mapping")
data <- dbFetch(result)

#updating the choices
updateSelectInput(session,"Client Rollup",choices = unique(data$'Client Roll Up'))
})
}
```

But the choices are not updating with the new data

Comment: Try `updateSelectInput`: https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/1.2.0/updateSelectInput.html

Comment: Hi Ryan, I have tried **updateSelectInput**, but its not working. Please find the above edited code.

Comment: Well, try using the function without the database data (make you're own toy data). Get the `updateSelectInput` function working, then deal with the database. Looking at the code, there's probably other issues causing the problem (`values` doesn't exist in the server).